# Can "to make someone crazy" be translated as "jemanden in (zum?) Wahnsinn bringen"

Tags: word-usage, idiom

I was wondering if one can say "jemanden zum Wahnsinn bringen" for "to make someone crazy"?
One can say

> Dieser Satz bringt mich durcheinander.

which means "This sentence confuses me."

and

> Diese Geschichte meiner Freundin hat mich zum Lachen gebracht. (= My friend's cracked me up.)

Comment: Just to add: if you wanted to express that the sentence confuses you it'd be easier to just say "Dieser Satz verwirrt mich"

Comment: Ja, kann man auch so sagen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would rather say

> jmd. in den Wahnsinn treiben

As in

> Meine Freundin treibt mich in den Wahnsinn.

Equivalently you could say

> Meine Freundin macht mich wahnsinnig.

But you usually wouldn't use `bringen` together with `Wahnsinn`.

**EDIT** 
(as response to @thekeyofgb's comment) Es gibt:

> etwas ist zum Wahnsinnigwerden

As in

> Diese Bauanleitung von IKEA ist zum Wahnsinnigwerden.

but I wouldn't use `zum Wahnsinn treiben`.

Comment: Könnte man "zum Wahnsinn treiben" sagen?

Comment: My german friends always say ' Er macht mich verrückt' .

Comment: @thekeyofgb: I'd say so, yes. "Diese Bauanleitung von IKEA treibt mich zum Wahnsinn" ist korrekt. Sowohl grammatikalisch als auch inhaltlich...